# Why does my jasmine test for component with method in ngOnInit to be truthy failing?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

I am writing test for a component to check its truthfulness.The component's ngOnInit() retrieves data from local storage and has a  method which sets some data

my component:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.recordState =  JSON.parse(localStorage['mystate']);
      this.populateData();

}
```

my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake((key: string): String => {
      return JSON.stringify({'mystate': {'testtext': 'hello'}});
  });
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

     it('should create', () => {  
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

error:

```
should create FAILED
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
            at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
            at TestComponent.ngOnInit (webpack:///./src/app/TestComponent?:22:46)
            at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9547:19)
            at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10811:20)
            at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10773:16)
            at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11406:38)
            at debugCheckDirectivesFn (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11366:13)
            at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/SearchActionsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:10:5)
            at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11358:21)
```

Comment: Your test is failing because whatever is in localStorage['mydata'] is not valid JSON.

Comment: seems like there is no issue with json added my json and before each in test in the question @codequiet

Comment: I don’t think localStorage is getting populated via your spy. Can you log the value of localStorage[‘mydata’] in ngOnInit to double-check? My guess is the value is undefined.

Comment: Can you try: create the component after declaring the spy? I mean the spy should be available before the instance is created and ngOnInit is called.